# How can I create a whole new dictionary in last random dictionary QAQ

Tags: python

```
dic = {1: 1, 3: 3, 5: 6, 6: 6}
```

new_mappping is reverse from dic `{1: [1], 3: [3], 6: [5, 6]}`

```
for keys, values in new_mapping.items():
    if keys not in new_sort.items():
        if values not in new_sort.items():
            new_sort = new_mapping
            for keys,values in new_sort.items():
                lens = len(values)
                ky = {keys: values}
                lll[lens] = ky
```

output from code:

```
{1: {3: [3]}, 2: {6: [5, 6]}}
```

desired output:

```
{1: {1: [1], 3: [3]}, 2: {6: [5, 6]}}
```

Comment: I really don't understand why{1:1} not contains in new dict

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post [mre]. What is `new_sort`, what is `lll`?

Comment: sorry this is my first time use so I was a little bit confused.

Comment: new_sort and lll is both empty {}

Comment: Please, edit the question and make the snippet [mre]! What is `{1: 1, 3: 3, 5: 6, 6: 6}` at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
#INPUT
dic = {1: 1, 3: 3, 5: 6, 6: 6}

#Step 1 - change keys to values and values to keys
rev_dic={}
[rev_dic.update({v: rev_dic[v]+[k]}) if v in rev_dic else rev_dic.update({v: [k]}) for k, v in dic.items()]


#Step 2 - create new dictionary by list length
new_dic = {k:{} for k in range(1,max([len(v) for v in rev_dic.values()])+1)}


#Lastly, insert the dictionary in new_dic by dics' value list length
[new_dic[len(val)].update({key:val}) for key,val in rev_dic.items()]
new_dic
```

Output:

```
{1: {1: [1], 3: [3]}, 2: {6: [5, 6]}}
```